# how to access the mac ress id

Tags: android, android-wifi

now i am creating a one android app in that i m getting some problems that is what i want is
in my device i have mac address id.. in my android app i want to do if that mac address id is match only than app will run otherwise  it may not work .. is like that we can do or not...

i am doing like this but i m not getting

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
 String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

and i taken 
 
also but not work.. plzz help me sir.. i want the simple code how to access that with my mac address

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getMACAddress(final String interfaceName) {
     String macaddress = "";
     try {
         final List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
         for (final NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
             if (interfaceName != null) {
                 if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName)) continue;
             }
             final byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
             if (mac==null) continue;
             final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
             for (int idx=0; idx <= mac.length; idx++)
                 buf.append(String.format("%02X:", mac[idx]));
             if (buf.length()>=0) buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);
                 macaddress = buf.toString();
             if(!macaddress.equals("")) break;
         }
     } catch (final Exception ex) { } 
     return macaddress ;
 }
```